# How to add new propertry in Kinetic js Object (ie. line, circle)

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I need to add new property in kinetic js object. For example, in Circle create,

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
x: mouseX,
y: mouseY,
radius: 4,
name : 'circle',
id: 'point'+uniqueID(),
fill: 'black',
stroke: 'black',
strokeWidth: 1,
draggable : true,});
```

I want to add two property like,

```
circle.lines = new Array();
circle.adjNode = new Array();
```

when I call **`stage.toJSON()`** then two extra properties do not find in json dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .setAttr to add a property to KineticJS's property bag and will be serialized during stage.toJSON:

```
circle.setAttr("lines",[]);
circle.setAttr("adjNode",[]);
```